# swagger-codegen API converts types to string

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen

Here is my interface for my swagger app:

```
@SwaggerDefinition(
    ...
)
@Api(
    produces = "application/json",
    protocols = "http",
    tags = {"Service"}
)
@Path("/v1/{userId}/Services")
public interface ServiceApiV1 {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @AsyncTimed
    @ApiOperation(
        value = "Retrieves a service instance",
        tags = "Service"
    )
    @Path("/{serviceId}")
    void fetchService(@Suspended AsyncResponse asyncResponse,
                      @ApiParam @PathParam("userId") UserId userId,
                      @ApiParam @PathParam("serviceId") ServiceId serviceId
    );

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @AsyncTimed
    @ApiOperation(
        value = "Retrieves a list of services",
        tags = "Service"
    )
    @Path("/")
    void fetchServices(@Suspended AsyncResponse asyncResponse,
                          @ApiParam @PathParam("userId") UserId userId
    );
}
```

I tried to use `@ApiParam(type = "UserId")` but it still uses string (I also tried to use the full path to `UserId`, like `com.myservice.UserId`)

As you can see, I have a specific type for `UserId` and one for `ServiceId`. When I run `swagger-codegen` the API generated, however, convert these arguments to type `string`

Is it possible to have Swagger generate the API clients, but keep the type of PathParams as I have defined them here?

(And yes, the `swagger.json` has these parameters of type `string` which makes sense why the codegen is then generating these as a string. So I guess the correct question is how to make Swagger generate the parameters are the more advance types as they are)

**UPDATE** So using full path does generate the right `type` for my `swagger.json`. However, the generated API still uses a `String` :(

Comment: You could try to state the type like this `@ApiParam(type = UserId)`

Comment: @moondaisy, well, `type` has to be `string`. So I did try `type = "UserId"` but that still did not work.

Comment: What you could do, now that your `swagger.json` has the correct `type`, is check what is the `datatype` value of your parameter once it gets processed. By running `java -DdebugOperations -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate  -i swagger.json  -l java` you get a json with the values used in the templates. You could check if the `datatype` of your parameter there is a `String` and try with other languages to see where in the swagger-codegen code this transformation might occur (I looked around but wasn't able to find anything)